# MS Access. Show only values higher than highest single value?

Tags: ms-access

How can I show only order totals higher than the highest single price from the computer table calculated on the fly as the values can change?
Thanks

***query result***

[image]

Comment: Post some sample data then explain what you trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean by `highest single price`?

Comment: Some order totals are multiple computers and I need to only display orders with a value higher than the most expensive single computer.

Comment: So after summing `Order Total` you need to compare with max value computer and return only those records `Order Total` > `Max(ComputerValue)`, am I right?

Comment: Order Total: [Price]>Max("price") i tried that in the field but i have price in more than one table. Can you specify the computer table?

Comment: Yes, that can be specified.